# There should be exactly one MIME attachment with Content-ID Exception in CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I get following error when i try to Consume a service in the Production environment which expects a MTOM attached file .

I have created the client in CXF and enabled MTOM in the following way.

```
                        service= new FileTransferService();
                        //service.setHandlerResolver(new JaxWsHandlerResolver());
                        port=service.getFileTransferServicePort();
                        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
                        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
                        binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

The error that i get is

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: BEA-382116: There should be exactly one MIME attachment with Content-ID = '3fbc960c-ac11-4bdb-b699-cdda584344a8@http://cxf.apache.org/'.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:211)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.transferFileService(Unknown Source)
    at com.file.transfer.SoaTransfer.transferToWebService(SoaTransfer.java:200)
    at com.file.transfer.SoaTransfer.run(SoaTransfer.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:767)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:939)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:963)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:767)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: BEA-382116: There should be exactly one MIME attachment with Content-ID = '3fbc960c-ac11-4bdb-b699-cdda584344a8@http://cxf.apache.org/'.
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:221)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:65)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:221)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:429)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1988)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1824)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:583)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:221)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:276)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:170)
        ... 7 more
```

**However** when i remove the cxf jars that i have added for another client WebService that only downloads a file from a Host WebService, this service works fine and the file is also added and transferred as an attachment.

Following is the list of jars that i remove to make the service work

```
cxf-2.0.6.jar , geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar , geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar , geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.3.jar , jaxb-api-2.0.jar , jaxb-impl-2.0.5.jar , jaxb-xjc-2.0.jar , neethi-3.0.2.jar , spring.jar , stax-utils-20060502.jar , velocity-1.4.jar , velocity-dep-1.4.jar , wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar , wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar , xml-resolver-1.2.jar , XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
```

**EDIT:**

Please note that the cxf version that i am using is 2.0.6

Comment: That's a lot. Are you not using maven? If you are using maven can you share pom file? Also share the entity which taking the MTOM attachment within it.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade Hi, sorry for the late reply. Just FYI, i could resolve the issue by upgrading to CXF 2.7.18. It was related to this reported issue http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/MTOM-producer-different-content-id-in-XOP-Include-and-MIME-part-for-the-same-attachment-td547750.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with cxf when the service sends an attachment with MTOM to any third party Web Service. Because of this issue :- 
[CXF MTOM producer for third party issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2669)

Upgrading to CXF 2.7.18 resolved the issue.